# Enable Scanning+Printer from print server

Tags: printing, printer, network-printer, print-server

we multiple the multiple printer's in our office (HP laserjet Pro MFP M127) which i now mostly configured on print server. The problem is with some people want to scan the documents from these printer! If printer installed from print server than the installed driver does not give option to scan the document unless it was directly installed on user machine. What can i do to solve this problem, so they can scan & print both managed by print server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your server:

- Set up a SHARED folder - place where your printer will send it's scans
- Create user account just for scanning purposes, lets call it "ScanUser" and give him FULL permission on your newly created SHARED folder

On your printer:

- Set up a SCAN TO FOLDER, SCAN TO SMB, SCAN TO NETWORK or whatever else they are calling it option, printer should have those steps inside of his USER MANUAL.

After that your users can access their scans from that SHARED folder.

If you need more help, feel free to ask.

Comment: The printer model i share doesn't have any SMB scanning options.

Comment: Seems like that printer is pretty "dumb" it does not support FTP either, just "Scan by using the HP Scan software (Windows)". Maybe you could install his software on your sever and put "HP Scan" shortcut on (in my answer mentioned) share. Then, maybe, your users will be able to start that app from there scan their document and pull it from that share to their computer. That is the only thing crossing my mind, maybe it will work, maybe it won't. Gl.